# Property of an abstract class?

Tags: python, abstract-class

I am doing a transition to Python and I find something confusing.
Properties in Java or C# are declared after the class declaration.
In Python properties are declared in the contractor:
`self.x = ...`.

I want to have an abstract class that cannot be instantiated but classes that inherits from it has the same property.

To make things even more clear.

I have `Shirt` abstract class that should have a property like

```
self.type = "Shirt"
```

So all `Shirts` (T shirt, jacket, coat, etc..) `self.type` will be `"Shirt"`.

Right now all I have is this for example:

```
class Shirt(object):

__metaclass__ = ABCMeta

class BlackShirt(Shirt):
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.__str__()
        self.value = self.Value.Basic.name

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'type': self.type,
            'value': str(self.value)
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return "Black Shirt"
```

Comment: In Python, those are called "attributes" of a class instance, and  "properties" means something else.They aren't declared, they come into existence when some value is assigned to them, often in the class' `__init__()` method. You can't create an instance of an abstract class, so if this is done in one, a concrete subclass would have to call its base's `__init__()` in its own `__init__()`, which can easily been done using `super()`. Alternatively they could just do it directly themself, it desired.

Comment: The code in your question isn't valid Python—that's not how an abstract class would be defined. It also looks like you're using Python 2.x, so you should also tag your question appropriately if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `abstractproperty` is what you are looking for, it allows you to define abstract property that the implementation must implement with the same name.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractproperty

class Abstract(ABC):

    @abstractproperty
    def type(self):
        pass


class Shirt(Abstract):

    @property
    def type(self):
       return "Shirt"


shirt = Shirt()
print(shirt.type)
```